# Gitlab Auto Deploy failing to connect to Docker

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker, gitlab-autodevops

I've got Gitlab installed on Kubernetes using Helm and try to get Auto DevOps working but I'm getting the following issue from the Auto DevOps pipeline:

```sh
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
$ if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then # collapsed multi-line command
$ /build/build.sh
Logging in to GitLab Container Registry with CI credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
Building Dockerfile-based application...
Attempting to pull a previously built image for use with --cache-from...
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
No previously cached image found. The docker build will proceed without using a cached image
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
Cleaning up file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I've read abt the issues with Docker-in-Docker, but I couldn't get it to work.

I also tried setting the `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/` variable, but I still get the same error.

```sh
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?
```

My Gitlab Runner Helm values looks like this:

```yaml
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.mydomain.com
privileged: true
rbac:
  create: true
runnerRegistrationToken: mytoken
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      executor = "docker"
      privileged = true
      environment = ["DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="]
      [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        privileged = true
```

I tried using the [Auto-DevOps `.gitlab-ci.yml` template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml).

My cluster is integrated into Gitlab using the cluster certificate method and running simple CI/CD like

```yaml
test_project:
  stage: test
  script:
  - npm run test
```

Works fine

I tried `docker:18.09.7`, `docker:19.03.1` and `docker:latest` (and the corresponding `-dind` services, with or without setting `DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/`)

I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Update

I got this issue resolved with help from the Gitlab Support.
My issue was that I had to use `[runners.kubernetes]` config and set `privileged` to `true` there. I was only setting it in `[runners.docker]` as I thought that Kubernetes Gitlab Runners would that config.